# How can I set Ingest attachment(elasticsearch) plugin options with Java API?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, java

I'm using [Ingest Attachment Processor Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.4/using-ingest-attachment.html) on elasticsearch. I need to set attachment options(`indexed_chars`, `properties`, `ignore_missing` etc.) with Java API. How can I do that?

I am creating index and setting pipeline like below:

```
String id = ...
Map<String, Object> row = ...
client.prepareIndex(indexName, "my_type", id)
                    .setSource(row)
                    .setPipeline("my_pipeline")
                    .execute();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found answer, If you have nested document you must use `foreach` else build json like [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/5.4/using-ingest-attachment.html)

Document:

**Solution:**

```
try (XContentBuilder jsonBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()) {
    BytesReference pipelineSource = jsonBuilder.startObject()
            .field("description", "Extract attachment information")
            .startArray("processors")
              .startObject()
                .startObject("foreach")
                  .field("field", "my_field")
                  .startObject("processor")
                    .startObject("attachment")
                      .field("field", "_ingest._value.my_base64_field")
                      .field("target_field", "_ingest._value.my_base64_field")
                      .field("ignore_missing", true)
                      .field("indexed_chars", -1)
                    .endObject()
                  .endObject()
                .endObject()
              .endObject()
            .endArray()
            .endObject().bytes();
    client.admin().cluster().preparePutPipeline("my_pipeline",
            pipelineSource, XContentType.JSON).get();
}
```

**OR**

you can put below json manually

**Result:**

```
http://localhost:9200/_ingest/pipeline/my_pipeline

{
  "my_pipeline": {
    "description": "Extract attachment information",
    "processors": [
      {
        "foreach": {
          "field": "my_field",
          "processor": {
            "attachment": {
              "field": "_ingest._value.my_base64_field",
              "target_field": "_ingest._value.my_base64_field",
              "ignore_missing": true,
              "indexed_chars": -1
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Am using RestHighLevelClient, so am not able to use `.admin()` method., instead of that which method or approach i can follow...??

Comment: There is `.ingest().putPipeline()` method for RestHighLevelClient that you can use